# Why does running the SAGA Upslope Area tool in QGIS result in a 0 (zero) to 0 (zero) histogram and an all black layer?

Tags: qgis, area, watershed, catchment-area

I am using QGIS in order to delineate a watershed, and am using 1/3 arcsecond DEMs.  I have created a Filled DEM using the SAGA Fill Sinks xxl (Wang & Liu) tool.  Next I ran the SAGA Channels and Drainage Basins tool, where the Channels were the only useful result.  From here, using the Coordinate Capture plugin I was able to exact a coordinate point on the most downstream part of the channel (or river in this case) that I am trying to create the watershed of.

From here, I ran the SAGA Upslope Area tool using the Filled DEM raster and the (x,y) coordinate I just captured.  The resulting layer that I created, however, was all black and the histogram distribution is `min=0` and `max=0`.  Why does this Upslope Area Layer not give me a result in which the `min = 0` and the `max = 100` and the resulting layer shows me the Upslope portion above that point in white and everything else in black?

What would the sources of my problems be? How do I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

The SAGA Upslope Area tool has worked for you correctly, though you would be seeing the black output layer (Upslope Area), plus Min=0 and Max=0 statistics in its Symbology panel.

Change the Max setting from zero to a small number (`< 1.0`), like `0.2` in my example (below).

[image]

You will find a blob around the point you have given as the outlet coordinates. That is your Upslope Area.
Please check the cell values by the `Identify tool` and adjust the max value accordingly.

[image]

Comment: First, thanks for you response.  So I have styled the Upslope Layer accordingly, but it is still coming up a blank screen - with whatever color value is associated with zero.  Even when I change the max to something like 0.2, nothing changes.  I used the Raster Information tool and found out the min=0 and max=100.  When I change the max to 100, still nothing changes.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean when you say check  the cell values with the Identify tool, but I think I got the correct min and max with the Raster Layer Information tool.

Comment: @ColterBirk I meant to check the cell value of the blob, but you won't be able to do so if you could not find it. I have to wonder which cell gave you max=100 in your raster. Can you post the output of the raster information tool?

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me was zooming in and capturing the coordinates of a point precisely in a channel. Points near but not in a channel had given me upslope areas too small to see.